# React Native: setState triggers unwanted Tab change in Tab Navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

Something does not make sense with my code.
I am using React Native to create a app.
In that app I am using a Tab Navigator.
It works fine until I call this.setState which for some reason triggers a unwanted Tab change from one tab to the other.

Why would setState trigger a Tab change??

This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, TextInput, StatusBar, Button } from 'react-native';
import { TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { Constants } from 'expo'
import { purple, white } from './utils/colors'


const R = require('ramda')


function CustomStatusBar({ backgroundColor, ...props }){
  return (
    <View style={{backgroundColor, height: Constants.statusBarHeight}}>
      <StatusBar translucent backgroundColor={backgroundColor} {...props} />
    </View>
  )
}


export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.handleDeckTitle = this.handleDeckTitle.bind(this)
  }

  state = {
    title: ''
  }

  renderItem = (sample) => {
    console.log('renderItem', sample)

    return <Text>SAMPLE DATA</Text>
  }

  handleDeckTitle(e){
    console.log('handleDeckTitle')
    console.log('e', e)
    console.log('this.state', this.state)

    this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
      title: e
    }));
  }


  submitDeckTitle(){
    console.log('submitDeckTitle')


  }
  render() {

    console.log('R', R)


    const Decks = () => {
      return (
        <View>
          <CustomStatusBar backgroundColor={purple} barStyle='light-content' />
          <Text>Decks!</Text>
        </View>
      )

    }



    const NewDeck = () => {


      return (
        <View>
          <CustomStatusBar backgroundColor={purple} barStyle='light-content' />
          <Text>What is the title of your new deck?</Text>
          <TextInput style = {styles.input} onChangeText={this.handleDeckTitle}/>
          <Button onPress={this.submitDeckTitle} title="Submit" />
        </View>
      )

    }

    const Tabs = TabNavigator({
      Decks: {
        screen: Decks
      },
      'New Deck': {
        screen: NewDeck
      },
    });

    return (

      <Tabs />

    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    paddingTop: 23,
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  input: {
      margin: 15,
      height: 40,
      borderColor: '#7a42f4',
      borderWidth: 1
   },
});
```

I don't see what is wrong with this code.
In fact I think it should just work normally but it does not.
It triggers a tab change when I call handleDeckTitle which then calls this.setState

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work now.

I changed the part that calls setState to be be a Separate Component with its own state.

Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, TextInput, StatusBar, Button } from 'react-native';
import { TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { Constants } from 'expo'
import { purple, white } from './utils/colors'


const R = require('ramda')


function CustomStatusBar({ backgroundColor, ...props }){
  return (
    <View style={{backgroundColor, height: Constants.statusBarHeight}}>
      <StatusBar translucent backgroundColor={backgroundColor} {...props} />
    </View>
  )
}


const Decks = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <CustomStatusBar backgroundColor={purple} barStyle='light-content' />
      <Text>Decks!</Text>
    </View>
  )

}




class NewDeck extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.handleDeckTitle = this.handleDeckTitle.bind(this)
  }

  state = {
    title: ''
  }

  handleDeckTitle(e){
    console.log('handleDeckTitle')
    console.log('e', e)
    console.log('this.state', this.state)

    this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
      title: e
    }));
  }

  render(){
    return (

          <View>
            <CustomStatusBar backgroundColor={purple} barStyle='light-content' />
            <Text>What is the title of your new deck?</Text>
            <TextInput style = {styles.input} onChangeText={this.handleDeckTitle}/>
            <Button onPress={this.submitDeckTitle} title="Submit" />
          </View>
        )

  }
}



const Tabs = TabNavigator({
  Decks: {
    screen: Decks
  },
  'New Deck': {
    screen: NewDeck
  },
});



export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    // this.handleDeckTitle = this.handleDeckTitle.bind(this)
  }

  state = {
    title: ''
  }

  renderItem = (sample) => {
    console.log('renderItem', sample)

    return <Text>SAMPLE DATA</Text>
  }




  submitDeckTitle(){
    console.log('submitDeckTitle')


  }
  render() {

    console.log('R', R)



    return (

      <Tabs />

    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    paddingTop: 23,
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  input: {
      margin: 15,
      height: 40,
      borderColor: '#7a42f4',
      borderWidth: 1
   },
});
```